# Javascript regex - remove all special characters except semi colon

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how do I remove all special characters from the string except the semi-colon?

sample string: `ABC/D A.b.c.;Qwerty`

should return: `ABCDAbc;Qwerty`

Answer (score 16):

You can use a regex that removes anything that isn't an alpha character or a semicolon like this `/[^A-Za-z;]/g`.

```js
const str = "ABC/D A.b.c.;Qwerty";
const result = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z;]/g, "");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Added in 0-9 to allow for alphanumeric strings as well.../[^A-Za-z0-9-]/g

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = "ABC/D A.b.c.;Qwerty";
var result = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z;]/g, "");​​ // 21ABCDAbc;Qwerty
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HkBfU/1)

Comment: Your code allows special characters: `[]/\_'` which are located in the ascii table between the lower and upper case letters.

Comment: Look here http://www.asciitable.com/ to see what you are also eliminating by doing `A-z`

Comment: @jfriend00. You're right fixed it after you comment on your answer. thanks