# how to replace all special characters except for spaces, . and brackets using java script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all the special characters in a form in BPM.

I have used

```
replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")
```

but this replaces all including .,() and spaces. I need to exclude some of these characters from being replaced

this is what i am trying to do in BPM

tw.local.sql="insert into BPM_RBD_GATEWAY values ('Forwarded','"+tw.local.RBDG.ProcessID+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.SolID+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.BranchCode+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.BranchName.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Name_brwr.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Name_Cooblgnt.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.CustID_Exstng.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Status_Loan.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Internl_Crdt_Ratng+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Scheme_ProdctType.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Acnt_Nmbr.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Loan_Amnt.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Bal_Outstandng.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Sanctnd_Period.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Deviatns_loan_sanctnIfany.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Loan_Sourcng+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Prevs_Rate_concsn.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Existng_Accnt_Type+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Existing_acnt_Rate.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Recomndr_Rate.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Arrears_Inspctn_Comnts.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.D_Borwr_Source_Empl_Profsn.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Borwr_Source_Details.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_prmry_Nature.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_prmry_Value.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_prmry_DtlsLimit.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_Collatrl_Nature.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_Collatrl_Value.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Secrty_Collatrl_DetLimt.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Deatils_ExistngBus_BrwrEnjoy.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Deatils_ExistngBus_TotGroup.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Deatils_ExistngBus_OprtvAccnt.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Deatils_ExistngBus_OtherPrdct.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Additional_Details.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Specific_BrRecom.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")+"','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','"+tw.local.RBDG.Br_Entry_User+"','"+tw.local.RBDG.Recomndr_Entry_User+"','','','','','','','','','"+tw.local.RBDG.Date+"','','','','','','','')";

Comment: Can you not just negate what you want to allow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405368/javascript-regex-remove-all-special-characters-except-semi-colon

Comment: i want to allow spaces between the words , dot(.) and brackets (). all others should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use replacer function to filter out matches which you don't want to replace

```
var excludes = [",", " ", "(", ")"];
var output = input.replace(/[_\W]/g, function(match){
  if ( excludes.indexOf(match) == -1 )
  {  
    match = "-";
  }
  return match;
}) ;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var input = "asda<>*(*_()(), wdsf %^&%^&";
var excludes = [",", " ", "(", ")"];
var output = input.replace(/[_\W]/g, function(match){
  if ( excludes.indexOf(match) == -1 )
  {  
    match = "-";
  }
  return match;
}) ;
alert(output);
```

Comment: replace(/[_\W]+/g, "-")  can this be modified to include % () and spaces and replacing all other special charaters

Comment: var input = "asda<>*(*_()(), wdsf %^&%^&";
var excludes = [",", " ", "(", ")"];
var output = input.replace(/[_\W]/g, function(match){
  if ( excludes.indexOf(match) == -1 )
  {  
    match = "-";
  }
  return match;
}) ;
alert(output); can you modify this to include % () and spaces and exclude all others

Comment: @arunsunny yes, you can add to `excludes` array those character which you don't want to replace

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "ABC/D A.b.c.;Qwerty(dgdf)";
var result = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z.;()]/g, "");
```

You'll end up with ABCDA.b.c.;Qwerty(dgdf)

Tell me if that worked out well for you